# Vanilla javascript changing data attribute of this

Tags: javascript

I am working on a page which is using Vanilla JavaScript and unfortunately I am only knowledgeable with jQuery. I have a function attached to my anchor tags to toggle additional content and I want to change `aria-expanded` from `false` to `true` on the anchor when it is clicked and then back to `false` when it is clicked again.

Here's what I've tried:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleMe(a) {
        var t = this;
        var e = document.getElementById(a);
        if (!e) return true;
        if (e.style.display == "none") {
            t.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
            e.style.display = "block"
        }
        else {
            t.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
            e.style.display = "none"
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

<a onclick="return toggleMe('content1')" aria-expanded="false">Expand content</a>

<div style="display: none" id="content1">
  <p>Expanded content here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean you're not knowledgeable with jQuery?

Comment: `this` refers to the window object, because you are using "old-school" event handling via HTML attributes. Either pass `this` in as a parameter as well, use bind as suggested in an answer ... or maybe use at least "vanilla JS" event handler binding, meaning `addEventListener` & Co. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your current implementation `this` in the function `toggleMe()` refers to `window` not to current element(anchor).

You can use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set the context

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```
<a onclick="return toggleMe.bind(this)('content1')" aria-expanded="false">Expand content</a>
```

OR, [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call)

> The `call()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually.

```
<a onclick="return toggleMe.call(this, 'content1')" aria-expanded="false">Expand content</a>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleMe(a) {
        var t = this;
        var e = document.getElementById(a);
        if (!e) return true;
        if (e.style.display == "none") {
            t.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
            e.style.display = "block"
        }
        else {
            t.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
            e.style.display = "none"
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

<a onclick="return toggleMe.bind(this)('content1')" aria-expanded="false">Expand content</a>

<div style="display: none" id="content1">
  <p>Expanded content here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and detailed explanation, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is in this line:

```
var t = this;
```

By default the value of this is the window object.
You can pass the value directly in the inline definition like:

```
<a onclick="return toggleMe('content1', this)" aria-expanded="false">Expand content</a>
```

```js
function toggleMe(a, currEle) {
    var t = currEle;
    var e = document.getElementById(a);
    if (!e) return true;
    if (e.style.display == "none") {
        t.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
        e.style.display = "block"
    }
    else {
        t.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        e.style.display = "none"
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="return toggleMe('content1', this)" aria-expanded="false">Expand content</a>

<div style="display: none" id="content1">
    <p>Expanded content here</p>
</div>
```